# Liszt Transcendental Étude No.1 (Prelude): Top voices on ascending fifth, descending second, descending second

Tags: theory, piano, analysis, arpeggios, romantic-period

I wanted to follow up to analyze the top voice on the right hand of the Liszt Transcendental Étude No.1 (Prelude).

Here are my (related) questions:

1. Is the red box note a B-flat or B? (It looks that in the 2nd bar, it only labels as B not B-flat, but in the 4th bar, it labels as B-flat. In both bars, the previous appearance of the same note is written as B-flat with $b$ or $\flat$.)
2. According to Aaron [Liszt Transcendental Étude No.1 (Prelude) -- chord progression along the Arpeggio (in the first 4 bars)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/130461), saying that

> > **Top**

> > This is a melodic, diatonic sequence: ascending fifth, descending second, descending second.

But this is only partially true, not entirely true. The one ascending, and two descending patterns go differently at least in those blue, green, and orange, pink lines.

Are there some good logics behind these different patterns here?

Of course, we know the music cannot be fully theoretically composed -- but I wanted to know what *Liszt wants us to do, what is his mindset, in his Transcendental Étude No.1 (Prelude) in C MAJOR!*

[image]

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. 1) It should be Bb in every case; it's just an error in the score. If you look at a more modern edition (try the Zoltán Gárdonyi edition on [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/%C3%89tudes_d%27ex%C3%A9cution_transcendante,_S.139_(Liszt,_Franz)), you'll see the Bb included each time. 2) The pattern is the same every time, as specified in the other post. Are you asking why sometimes they are minor seconds versus major seconds? This is because it's a diatonic sequence, so the notes are adjusted to stay within the scale.

Comment: >> "they are minor seconds versus major seconds?" YES.

Comment: >> "This is because it's a diatonic sequence, so the notes are adjusted to stay within the scale." That is great. I just wonder whether there was some exception. So are there also Major 5th vs minor 5th issues here for ascending? Thanks!

Comment: There's no major and minor fifth. A fifth is always seven semitones. Doesn't have a major and minor variant.

Answer (score 1):

The B♭ in the first bar is there as an extra reminder that it IS a B♭ as per the previous accidental, not the B natural suggested by the Em/G [modulation](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/112056) at the start of the sequence.

Since you've been reminded that it's a B♭ in the 1st bar, a competent pianist need not be reminded again for the same sequence in the 3rd bar.